# Adding event listeners to dynamically added elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

So right now, I understand that in order to attach an *event listener* to a **dynamically** added element, you have to redefine the listener after adding the element.

Is there any way to bypass this, so you don't have to execute a whole extra block of code?

Comment: A vanilla js solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/1385441

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can define your function once, and it will execute for any dynamically added elements.

for example

```
$('#staticDiv').on('click', 'yourSelector', function() {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to use .on() on events that are not in native jquery. i.e. I need to use it with a Jquery plugin.

Comment: @Wiz: you can bind to any event

Comment: @zerkms Well I'm trying to use it with Hovercard, and $('.class').on('hovercard', function(){}); is not working, when the usual syntax is $('.class').hovercard(function(){});

Comment: @Wiz - Delegated event handling (which is what you need for this solution) only works with events that propagate.  This includes most mouse related events, but not all events.  it looks like you're trying to use it with a `hovercard` event.  That isn't really an event is it?

Comment: @Wiz is `.class` also dynamically added? Also your missing the selector. `parentDiv` needs to exist when your binding the event, you may need to bind to the `document` if you don't have a static parent element to bind to.

Comment: @Jack I changed it to $(document).on('hovercard', '.class', function(){});, but right now, its not working for static or dynamic elements.

Comment: @Wiz - I don't think you can use `.hovercard()` with `.on()`.   `.on()` works with events, not with jQuery plugins calls.

Comment: @jfriend00 then is there any way I can just define the event once and let it work for all dynamically added elements, or is the only way to add an event listener every time I add an element.

Comment: @Wiz you might be able to hook in to the `mouseover event` of a parent element and over there initialize the plugin.

Comment: @Wiz, one would have to examine how the hovercard plugin source code works in order to answer that.  Next time, please specify important details like this in your question.  As it is your question asks about event listeners, but what you really want is hovercard installation so the answers to the question you wrote don't help you at all with your  real problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 yea I thought it would be like any other event.

Comment: @Wiz - `.hovercard` isn't an event - it's a method call.  `.on()` works with events.

Comment: @Wiz Here's a very basic [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aauMs/1/) to get you started, you might want to make sure that nothing adverse happens when you call the plugin multiple times on an element. ( note I started the fiddle off of one of demos since I didn't see a cdn for the hovercard plugin)

Comment: i'm using `.one("mouseenter"` and hitting the same hurdle can anyone help? @Wiz

Comment: wont work. It still works on 1 element

Comment: What if the ‘staticDiv’ itself is dynamic? Can you still delegate the event listener?

Comment: @HPWD No, but you can always go further up the DOM and if need be delegate directly on the `body` (for example `$('body').on('click','.yourSelector', function () {...})`

Comment: I just realized you said `body` and not `document`. I've updated my code accordingly. I just wanted to make that distinction since the other answer below references the `$(document)`. I missed that on my initial review.

Comment: @HPWD both will work, the document is above the body in the dom. There isn't really going to be much practical difference but in general you want to bind your handler to the closest element possible so it doesn't "bubble" up further then it needs to. I recommend you read up on [event bubbling](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) to get a better understanding.

Comment: @Jack Is this still relevant today ? It doesnt seem to be working for me !

Comment: @tejas Yes, it still works today, are you sure that the "static div" exists on the DOM when you are running you code?

Comment: @Jack, Thank you for your response. I think there was something I couldnt understand and refactored the code a bit and it started working.

Answer (score 50):

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', handler);
```

Where `click` is an event name, and `handler` is an event handler, like reference to a function or anonymous function `function() {}`

PS: if you know the particular node you're adding dynamic elements to - you could specify it instead of `document`.

Comment: Don't use `$(document)`. The event should be bound to the closest static parent.

Comment: @Joseph Silber: I've added PS for that. And "don't use" is too much categorical. There are valid cases for using it (don't even mention it is specified in jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 6):

You are dynamically generating those elements so any listener applied on page load wont be available. I have edited your fiddle with the correct solution. Basically jQuery holds the event for later binding by attaching it to the parent Element and propagating it downward to the correct dynamically created element.

```
$('#musics').on('change', '#want',function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.from-group').val(($('#want').is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
    var ans=$(this).val();
    console.log(($('#want').is(':checked')));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swoogie/1rkhn7ek/39/

Answer (score 1):

When adding new element with jquery plugin calls, you can do like the following:

```
$('<div>...</div>').hoverCard(function(){...}).appendTo(...)
```