# jQuery: a generated button does not catch a click event

Tags: jquery, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery adding event listeners to dynamically added elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065329/jquery-adding-event-listeners-to-dynamically-added-elements)

jQuery bit:

I append an input field with some text to a div:

```
        shareVisual = '<div class="individual-share">' + '<input type="number" value="1" /> X ' + classname.val() + '@' + classcurrency.val() + ' ' + classprice.val() + ' per share ' + '<button type="button" class="remove-share">Remove</button></div>';
        listOfSharesBox.append(shareVisual);
```

And then i try to catch an on-click event:

```
$("#list-of-shares").bind('click', '.remove-share', function() {
    $(".remove-share").closest("div").find(".individual-share").remove();
});
```

Why does the DIV not get removed?

Cheers.

P.S.

when i change my code to this:

```
$("#list-of-shares").bind('click', '.remove-share', function() {
    $(".remove-share").closest("div").remove();
});
```

All of the dynamically generated inputs get deleted within the div.

Comment: Use `on` method http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the jquery 1.7 means try like this

```
$(".remove-share").on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

otherwise use

```
$(".remove-share").bind('click',function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

Comment: I altered the code and now i have this:

    $(listOfSharesBox).bind('click', 'remove-share', function() {
         $(this).closest("div").find(".individual-share").remove();
    });

Unfortunately, when i click on a button, it deletes all the DIVs within the parent div. All i want is to delete only a signle div that has a button associated with it.

Comment: no yuo should not have like this  $(listOfSharesBox) because listOfSharesBox is a variable not a dom object

Answer (score -1):

Try using the 'live' keyword which copes with dynamically generated controls:

```
$(".remove-share").live('click', function() {
$(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

Comment: `live` has been deprecated.  You should use `on` instead