# Focus event not working on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am adding input dynamically using jQuery. After that i am trying to use focus event to generate yet another input group. Here is the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/sk8UG/)
and the snippet is below

HTML:

```
    <div class='row' id='addChild'>
    <input type='name' name='child0' id='child0'>
    <input type='name' name='phone0' id='phone0'>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#child0").focus(function() {
         $('#addChild').append("<input type='name' name='child1' id='child1'><input type='name' name='phone1' id='phone1'>");
     });
     $("#child1").focus(function() {
         $('#addChild').append("<input type='name' name='child2' id='child2'><input type='name' name='phone2' id='phone2'>");
     });
   });
```

On focus of #child0 it will create #child1. But, on focus of #child1, it does nothing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use event [**delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('#addChild').on("focus","#child1",function() {

 // do your work here 
});
```

**NOTE:** You have to use event delegation on element which are created at run time since those elements are not available during document ready

**Document Says**

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Comment: Could you please explain event deledation and why the former method doesn't work here

Comment: it doesnt work gzix because after the object is created you need to add to it an onFocus, but you dont do that, with delegation it's like jQuery.live() deprecated function, read a bit about .live()

Comment: @gzix Your code was not working because you was binding event before event is created.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to delegate using pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).on('focus','#child1',function() {
    $('#addChild').append("<input type='name' name='child1' id='child1'><input type='name' name='phone1' id='phone1'>");
 });
```

## [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sk8UG/1/)

> Binding event before element in not created and not presend in DOM.
>   Event Delegation is method for jquery event on dynamic content.

**[Detilas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065329/jquery-adding-event-listeners-to-dynamically-added-elements)**

Answer (score 1):

As you asked explain delecation **Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener**, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Below code will work fine

```
    $('#addChild').on("focus","#child1",function() {
    $(this).append("<input type='name' name='child2' id='child2'><input type='name' name='phone2' id='phone2'>");
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are binding the `on focus` event, the element with the id `child1` has not been created yet. Event listeners can only be bound on existing elements. As Bala explained, event delegation is the way to go.

As an alternative you could bind the new event after creating a new element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#child0").focus(function() {
         $('#addChild').append("<input type='name' name='child1' id='child1'><input type='name' name='phone1' id='phone1'>").focus(function() {
         $('#addChild').append("<input type='name' name='child2' id='child2'><input type='name' name='phone2' id='phone2'>");
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#addChild').on("focus","#child1",function() {

  // do your work here 
});
```