# create dynamically buttons to show dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a button (create) and when it's clicked, it creates a new button (Change coordinates) that should be able to open dialog when it's clicked.

First of all I created body of dialog window, I created this via JavaScript, this is just how it looks like in HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Change coordinates">
  <p class="validateTips">Both fields are required.</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="lon">Longitude (decimal)</label>
    <input type="text" name="lon" id="lon" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <label for="lat">Latitude (decimal)</label>
    <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now when create button is clicked I crate new button able to open dialog:

```
$( "#create" ).button().on( "click", function()
{
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.id = "change_coord";
    var t = document.createTextNode("Change coordinates");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
});
```

And this is how my dialog looks like:

```
dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          width: 350,
          modal: true,
          buttons:{
                "Create an account": addUser,
                Cancel: function(){
                    dialog.dialog( "close" );
                }
          },
          close: function(){
                form[ 0 ].reset();
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
          }
});
```

Weird is that it works when I'm creating body of dialog and button to open it in

```
$(function()
{
....
});
```

But when I'm dynamically creating this button to open dialog it doesn't work at all.
[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/x11o25v6/15/) is my fiddle to show you my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/2006429), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15090942/2006429), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12065329/2006429), and so many others. Try "jquery dynamic element listener" on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Per Charlietfl, who is correct "live" has been deprecated, but it does still remains a common solution to the problem.  The other method I've used, which also works is:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter","#lsTMFmenu", function() {
```

However, I cannot get JQuery to work against dynamically loaded HTML using just $("#selector").on(), I must use $(document).on statement shown above.

Thanks.

Comment: [`live()` has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for years now. Answer is backwards...should use `on()`

Comment: I understand live has been deprecated but on will not provide the functionality requested.  I use this daily and always have to revert to "live" when I have dynamically generated content containing more JQuery.  The other option is to use $(document).on("click","#selector", function() { *** but this is not as efficient on large html pages with many elements.  Harsh.

Comment: There are good performance reasons why live() was deprecated and `on()` was created. That change happened at the same time in the library. Also you don't have to go all the way up to document to delegate. Any fixed asset ancestor can be used