# How pass row to other table with only jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JavaScript, and I want pass row from table to other table like this:

[image: Tables]

Pass rows from table to other table without repeat the same row..
How do i?

I have this:

```js
$(".btn_add").on("click", function() {
  var column1 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent;
  var column2 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent;
  var column4 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[3].textContent;
  var column5 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[4].textContent;
  $("#second_table").append("<tr><td>" + column1 + "</td><td>" + column2 + "</td><td>" + column4 + "</td><td>" + column5 + "</td><td><input type='number'></td><td>--</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn_remove'>- Remove</button></td></tr>");

  $(".btn_remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="first_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Monitor A</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7.5</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mouse B</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>12.4</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Keyboard D</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>22.35</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Motherboard C</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table id="second_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Calculated Field</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to create a pseudo-class to identify the rows by their product id. In my example, I just named it e.g. "copy_1". You can then check if the ID already exists in the 2nd table. I also added, that the input field will be increased to add one product. If you don't want this, just remove the else-statement.

Side note: With the "on"-method, you can declare a global listener, which also applies on dynamically generated elements. You can use it for the remove button as well and don't need to redeclare it everytime, when someone adds a product. I change this in my code as well. See this post for more information about it: [Jquery adding event listeners to dynamically added elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065329/jquery-adding-event-listeners-to-dynamically-added-elements)

```js
$(".btn_add").on("click", function() {
  var column1 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent;
  var column2 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent;
  var column4 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[3].textContent;
  var column5 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[4].textContent;
  // check if the row already exists in the 2nd table
  // if no, add the line to the 2nd table
  // if yes, add one product to the input field
  if($("#second_table .copy_"+column1).length == 0)
  {

    $("#second_table").append("<tr class='copy_"+column1+"'><td>" + column1 + "</td><td>" + column2 + "</td><td>" + column4 + "</td><td>" + column5 + "</td><td><input type='number' value='1'></td><td>--</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn_remove'>- Remove</button></td></tr>");
  }
  else
  {
     var value = parseInt($("#second_table .copy_"+column1+" input").val()) + 1;
     $("#second_table .copy_"+column1+" input").val(value);
  }
});

$("body").on("click",".btn_remove", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="first_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Monitor A</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7.5</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mouse B</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>12.4</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Keyboard D</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>22.35</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Motherboard C</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table id="second_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Calculated Field</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just missing an event handler for the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event in the second table. You'l want to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) since the content is added dynamically.

The following code should do the trick:

```
$("#second_table").on("input", "input", function() {
  var input = $(this);
  var columns = input.closest("tr").children();
  var price = columns.eq(3).text();
  var calculated = input.val() * price;
  columns.eq(5).text(calculated);
});
```

There's a running snippet below. You'll see the price calculate in real-time as you change the inputs in the second table.

```js
$(".btn_add").on("click", function() {
  var column1 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent;
  var column2 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent;
  var column4 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[3].textContent;
  var column5 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[4].textContent;
  $("#second_table").append("<tr><td>" + column1 + "</td><td>" + column2 + "</td><td>" + column4 + "</td><td>" + column5 + "</td><td><input type='number'></td><td>--</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn_remove'>- Remove</button></td></tr>");

  $(".btn_remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

});

$("#second_table").on("input", "input", function() {
  var input = $(this);
  var columns = input.closest("tr").children();
  var price = columns.eq(3).text();
  var calculated = input.val() * price;
  columns.eq(5).text(calculated);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="first_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Monitor A</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7.5</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mouse B</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>12.4</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Keyboard D</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>22.35</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Motherboard C</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table id="second_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Calculated Field</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it's not the answer of the question. OP wants to know how to avoid multiple rows of the same product in the 2nd table.

Comment: @MichaelWalter I guess I misunderstood. +1 for your answer though