# Create child table when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a table that can be dynamically edited with HTML and Javascript.

I have a button in a row of a parent table and I want to create a child table inside the parent table when a button is clicked.
But my jquery is not called on click.

Class name is .childtbl.

**Edit**

I have create button colume propmotional title in every row. button is clickable only on first row and also I can create table row but in second row i am not able to crete table onlcick of button! I dont know why function is not call.You can see my code in snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i =0;
    $(".addmore").on('click', function () {
      // alert("ks");
        var count = $('#form_table')[0].rows.length;
        alert(count);
        var data = "<tr class='case'><td><span id='snum" + count + "'>" + count + ".</span></td>";
        data += "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='wname[]'/></td><td><button type=\"button\" id='newtrbtn' class='btn btn-success childtbl'>+ add new Title</button></td></tr>";
        $('#form_table').append(data);
        i++;
    });
    $(".childtbl").on('click', function () {

        alert("come from second");
        var count1 = $('#form_table1')[0].rows.length;
        alert(count1);
        var data1 = "<tr class='case1'><td><span id='snum1" + count1 + "'>" + count1 + ".</span></td>";
        data1 += "<td>Title:<input class='form-control' type='text' name='wr[]'/></td></tr>";
        $('#form_table1').append(data1);
        i++;
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='test'  method="post">
    <label class="label"> <strong> Warishan Names <strong> </label>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="form_table" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>S. No</th>
                <th>Promotional Header</th>
                <th>promotional Titile</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class='case'>
                <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' name='wname[]'/></td>
                <td><button type="button" class='btn btn-success childtbl'>+ add new Title</button> <br>
                    <table id="form_table1" class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr class='case1'>
<!--                       

         <td><span id='snum1'>1.</span></td>-->
    <!--                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' name='wr[]'/></td>-->
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td> </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ add new Header</button> <br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
</form>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what's wrong with your code. Can you give a bit more details about the expected behaviour, and what actually happens ?

Comment: As a side note, you actually don't need to add `1` to all your variable names in the second callback function you define. `var` declarations are function-scoped so the two functions' inner variables won't overlap.

Comment: I have create button coloum promotional title in every row. button is clickable and also I can create table row but only on first row! In second row i am not able to crete table onclick of button! I don't know why function is not call.You can see my code in snippet. @aurelienshz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Several points :

- Your event listener shouldn't try to listen to dynamically added content (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065329/jquery-adding-event-listeners-to-dynamically-added-elements)), see line 8 in the JS part of this snippet
- You were trying to retrieve the child table by its id (`var count1 = $('#form_table1')[0].rows.length;` and `$('#form_table1').append(data1);`). You have to dynamically find the row in which the button that was clicked is located, which you can achieve thanks to the value of `this` inside jQuery event listeners, see line 9

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addmore").on('click', function () {
        var count = $('#form_table')[0].rows.length;
        var data = "<tr class='case'><td><span id='snum" + count + "'>" + count + ".</span></td>";
        data += "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='wname[]'/></td><td><button type=\"button\" id='newtrbtn' class='btn btn-success childtbl'>+ add new Title</button><table class='table table-bordered'></table></td></tr>";
        $('#form_table').append(data);
    });
    $('form#test').on('click', '.childtbl', function () {
        var $titlesTable = $(this).next('table')[0];
        var titlesCount = $titlesTable.rows.length + 1;
        var data1 = "<tr class='case1'><td><span id='snum1" + titlesCount + "'>" + titlesCount + ".</span></td>";
        data1 += "<td>Title:<input class='form-control' type='text' name='wr[]'/></td></tr>";
        $($titlesTable).append(data1);
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='test' method="post">
    <label class="label"> <strong> Warishan Names <strong> </label>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="form_table" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>S. No</th>
                <th>Promotional Header</th>
                <th>promotional Titile</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class='case'>
                <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' name='wname[]'/></td>
                <td><button type="button" class='btn btn-success childtbl'>+ add new Title</button>
                    <table class="table table-bordered"></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ add new Header</button> <br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way your're creating the click events. They're created when the DOM loads and associated to current buttons, but when you create a button dinamically, that events are not associated to it.

To solve it, you can use **delegated events**. Use the on() function for an outer element (that is always going to exists, in your case the table@form_table, for example), and create the click events associating to the buttons inside. So change this...

```
$(".childtbl").on('click', function () {
```

... by this...

```
$('table#form_table').on('click','button.childtbl',function(e) {
```

... so the event would work for preexisting buttons or the dinamically generated. And `$(this)` inside of the new `on` function will still be associated to the button (not the table).

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much !Its work for me . But one more issue is  when i click button of second row ! my text field  is creating in first row instead of second row.

Comment: That's a different problem. You're selecting your pre-created `table#form_table1` that only exists in that first line. To create the new child table, I would get the current button `td` just with `$(this).closest('td')` and would create the whole new table in a variable and add it with `$(this).closest('td').append(myChildTableVar)`