# Jquery grouping event listeners for dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, event-handling, event-listener

After reading this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12065349/8547355), I changed the way I handled specific events in my application.

However, I ended up with a lot of code that seems "similar", and I was wondering if there's a way to group multiple event listeners that happen on the same parent.

Here's an example of 3 different buttons that submit some form. The buttons are added dynamically and not all of them might be available all the time.

```
const parentElement = $('#myBlock')
parentElement.on("submit", "form[data-action='button-1']", (evt) => {
  //do something
});

parentElement.on("submit", "form[data-action='button-2']", (evt) => {
  //do something else
});

parentElement.on("submit", "form[data-action='button-3']", (evt) => {
  //do magic
});
```

Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: All the event would do the same thing..?

Comment: No, each does something else

Comment: Then obviously you need to attach the event for each form separately..!

Comment: In other words, there is no better way?

Comment: You can attach the events at once though, but nevertheless, you need to handle the form submission conditionally inside the handler function..! :)